# How can I stop a long-running subroutine in my Form with a Button?

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

I have a Console app that displays a WinForms Form.

In the Form, the user clicks **button 1** and it runs a long subroutine.  I want to have a **button 2** that can kill the subroutine at any point.  However, the UI freezes when I click **button 1** until the subroutine has finished.  How can I get the UI to not freeze?

Comment: Is it a Console App or a WinForms App?  I'm thoroughly confused

Comment: it's a bit foggy, can't see well without a piece of code, I will just guess, try `Application.DoEvents();`

Comment: @chouaib -- NEVER use `Application.DoEvents()` http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/06/448560.aspx

Comment: You will have to use a multithreaded approach to keep the UI responsive.  That is unfortunately a very broad topic and quite a steep learning curve, so I'd recommend you go and start learning.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: To the OP, *please* clarify your question as your suggesting that this is a console app is absurdly confusing.

Comment: Console apps don't have buttons. They just have a black window with white text... you know, a console.

Comment: It's a console application.  I put in a UI for the times that someone might want to use the exe without the command prompt.  I have a variety of end users on this, some noobs and some scripters.  Most noobs will not want to use the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Your long-running code is blocking the UI thread, so you can no longer click the second button, nor interact with the UI in any way until the code is finished executing.

You'll need to move your long-running code to a separate thread. There are various (and newer) ways of doing this, but one way is the [BackgroundWorker](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker). It's pretty easy to learn, and wraps some nice functionality, like cancelling the thread.

Here's a short WinForms app to demonstrate. You have to explicitly enable the ability for the thread to be cancelled. In this example, the `while` loop continues indefinitely, but checks every 100ms to see if there's a request for it to be cancelled. When you click the second button, the cancellation request is sent, and the thread ends.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker bg;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bg = new BackgroundWorker
             {
                 WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
             };

        bg.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                if (bg.CancellationPending)
                    break;
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Done!");
        };
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bg.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bg.CancelAsync();
    }
}
```

Following up on chouaib's comment, another nice thing about using the BackgroundWorker in a WinForms environment is that you can drop and drop it onto your designer, similar to a Menu, Timer, etc. You can then access its members in the "properties" panel, setting "WorkerSupportsCancellation" to `true`, subscribing to events, etc.

---

From your comment:

> "is there a way to run this background process and be able to update the main userform? I keep getting the "cross-thread operation not valid control accessed from a thread other than the..." I want to run the long-running background operation, and have it update the main UI with text in a label (like a percentage of its progress)"

If you want to update the UI while the thread is running, you should do that from the ProgressChanged event. First, enable that option and subscribe to the event:

```
bg.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

bg.ProgressChanged += bg_ProgressChanged;
```

Then call `ReportProgress()` when you want to update the UI. You could pass back a percentage complete and some text, for instance:

```
bg.ReportProgress(50, "Almost there...");
```

Finally, update the UI from inside the event:

```
void bg_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var message = e.UserState.ToString();
    var percent = e.ProgressPercentage;

    lblStatus.Text = message + " " + percent;
}
```

Comment: nice tutorial, I'd just suggest you define all what is inside `Form()` by dragging and dropping a `BackgroundWorker` from the ToolBox's components, then do the settings ('WorkSupportCancellation = true' ...)

Comment: This backgroundworker works, (and so does running a thread), but is there a way to run this background process _and_ be able to update the main userform?  I keep getting the "cross-thread operation not valid control accessed from a thread other than the..."  I want to run the long-running background operation, and have it update the main UI with text in a label (like a percentage of its progress)

Answer (score -1):

You need to make it multithreaded as suggested in the comments.  The older way of doing this was manage your own thread.  Then along came the background worker (cheap and easy).  Now a days you have other options such as the Task Library.

Remember - anything the runs on the UI thread prevents the UI from sending and receiving events until that operation is finished.

Answer (score -2):

Look into the [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) component

Comment: This is more of a comment, not an answer.